# How to assert against a RequestError?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, nock

In a the following test, I am receiving a `RequestError`. How do I assert against this?

```
it('should timeout the request', async () => {
  const scope = nock('http://example.com')
    .get('/')
    .socketDelay(1000)
    .times(3)
    .reply(200, { example: true });

  const response = request.get({ ...baseOptions, timeout: 70 });

  await expect(response).rejects.toEqual(
    new Error('[Breaker: test-request] Request Timed out')
  );
});
```

Assertion error is:

```
Expected: [Error: [Breaker: test-request] Request Timed out]
Received:[RequestError: [Breaker: test-request] Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT]
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking - you *already* seem to be successfully mocking a request error. Also you seem to have asked the same thing [once already](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60840673/3001761).

Comment: The other question was how to mock a class, this is how to assert against a RequestError. In the `expect` I am able to create an Error object to assert against, but not sure how to specifically assert against an error of this type.

Comment: There are various options, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror